# NSData from bluetooth to integer

Tags: swift, bluetooth

I get data from bluetooth every 2 seconds,

```
func device(device: JDevice!, didUpdateData data: NSData!, type typeCode: Int8, error: NSError!) {
        print(data)
}
```

The print result is:

```
<6d000000>
<6e000000>
<6f000000>
<70000000>
<71000000>
<72000000>
```

How can I convert this data to an integer or string?

**EDIT** -------------------------

```
let des = data.description as NSString
            let dataAsString = des.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(1, data.description.characters.count-2))
            var value = UInt8(0)
            data.getBytes(&value, range: NSMakeRange(0, dataAsString.characters.count/2))
print(value)
```

I found the solution, but I am not very clear on why I use `dataAsString.characters.count` as the length of the range in the `data.getBytes` function.

I also got this error:

```
'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[_NSInlineData getBytes:range:]: range {0, 8} exceeds data length 4'
*** First throw call stack:
```

What does this error mean? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let des = data.description as NSString
            let dataAsString = des.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(1, data.description.characters.count-2))
            var value = UInt8(0)
            data.getBytes(&value, range: NSMakeRange(0, dataAsString.characters.count/2))
print(value)
```